# Jstl tag usage to format a negative number

Tags: java, jstl

Hi I want to display a negative number using "fmt:formatNumber" tag on jsp.
Now my problem is to display -300 as ($300) on UI, could any one please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${-number}" type="currency"/>
```